# g++ (MinGW), C++11 and SSE

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, mingw

When I try to compile the next simple example of code:

```
echo "#include <cmath>" | g++ -x c++ -c - -m64 -mfpmath=both -std=gnu++11 -o /dev/null
```

(along with `-m64` option is activated (by default) a using of **SSE** (say, **AVX**)).

It is appear the following error message:

```
In file included from <stdin>:1:0:
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/cmath:1040:11: error: '::double_t' has not been declared
c:\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/cmath:1041:11: error: '::float_t' has not been declared
```

Is this a bug?

Without `-mfpmath=both` option an error does not happen.

My workaround is to add the `-D__FLT_EVAL_METHOD__=2` (and `-Wp,-w` if `-Werror` is present, because of "is redefined" warning) to **g++**'s option list. I think that this is a dirty way.

Comment: it compiles without error against gcc 4.8.0 20121126 (prerelease).

Comment: Thanks. But what about 4.7.x? Can you test it?

Comment: It compiles as well against g++ 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1). Maybe your problem is mingw related?

Comment: Very similar to that. I try to do the same here (http://liveworkspace.org/), and it's works. But this is not true for the various builds of MinGW (such as MinGW, mingw-w64 (mingw-builds, and rubenvb)).

Comment: I get the same error with MinGW-builds

Comment: Compiles fine with gcc 4.7 on OS X. Blame MinGW for that.

Comment: @Dukales: Just throw that Windows outta the window. Get a proper Unix-like OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is in wrong commit on mingw-w64 trunk. I wrote a bug report for this. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a link to the bug report?

Comment: I write to mingw-w64 maillist. But this error is stranger. Mingw-builds rev3 doesn't have this error but rev4 have it. We discuss about it now

Comment: I have some research and find that it bug in multilib builds of gcc. I  run you example in all variants of builds and have next picture: it work on dwarf builds and 32-bit nomultilib builds; work with -m32 on 32-multilib builds;fail with -m64 on 32-multilib builds;fail on all 64-bit multilib builds. I try it on gcc-4.7.2 only.

Comment: This bug is fixed in mingw-w64 trunk. Next build of mingw-builds will be with this fix.